# Do we need to call SQLAllocHandle to allocate a SQLHSTMT before each call to SQLExecdirect

Tags: c++, odbc

I need to execute a series of T-sql statements as part of a transaction,I call SQLAllocHandle to allocate a handle of type SQLHSTMT before each call to SQLExecDirect to execute each t-sql statement. If I change the code to have a single call to SQLAllocHandle before the first SQLExecDirect then the subsequent calls to SQLExecDirect fail.

```
// This works
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, *connection, &sqlStmtHandle);
rc = SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLCHAR *)statement1, SQL_NTS);
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, *connection, &sqlStmtHandle);
rc = SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLCHAR *)statement2, SQL_NTS);


// This doesnt work. 
rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, *connection, &sqlStmtHandle);
rc = SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLCHAR *)statement1, SQL_NTS);
rc = SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLCHAR *)statement2, SQL_NTS);
```

Is this expected? If so why? is there a resource that clearly explains the semantics. Looking at the online documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlallochandle-function?view=sql-server-2017

```
"To request a statement handle, an application connects to a data source and then calls SQLAllocHandle before it submits SQL statements. "
```

This seems to indicate I shouldnt have to call SQLAllocHandle repeatedly but I am not entirely sure about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `SQLAllocHandle()` only during initialization of database, else it may lead to memory leak and performance issues. After a SQLExecDirect() command, the query result gets stored in the hDatabaseStatement ( auto memory allocation depending on the size of the result, **so no need to call  `SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT,...)` repeatedly**), which needs to be freed after every query.

```
void InitializeDatabase() // call one time
{
        SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hDatabaseEnv);
        SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDatabaseEnv, &hDatabase);
        SQLDriverConnect(/* */);
        SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDatabase, &hDatabaseStatement);
}

void DestroyDatabase() // call one time
{
    SQLFreeStmt(hDatabaseStatement, SQL_CLOSE);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDatabaseStatement);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDatabase);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hDatabaseEnv);        
}

void InsertItemDatabase(/**/)
{
    SQLExecDirect(hDatabaseStatement, wchar, SQL_NTS);
    SQLFreeStmt(hDatabaseStatement, SQL_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call SQLAllocHandle but you do need to reset the existing handle with a call to SQLFreeStmt with the option set to  SQL_CLOSE or call SQLCloseCursor.

You can look at the ODBC state transition tables for statement handles (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/statement-transitions?view=sql-server-2017) and see that you can't go directly from an executed statement to another execution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both of were accurate. Unfortunately I could only mark one of your responses as answer.